# Python: GroupBy DataFrame and add tally

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, count

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
df:
date         symbol    constituents
01-01-2022   SPY       AAPL
01-01-2022   SPY       MSFT
01-01-2022   SPY       TSLA
01-01-2022   GLD       AEM
01-01-2022   GLD       ABX
01-01-2022   GLD       KL
01-01-2022   GLD       WPM
```

I want to apply a tally using the `groupby` function to the DataFrame to get the following result

```
df:
ticker              AAPL   MSFT   TSLA   AEM  ABX  KL   WPM
date        symbol
01-01-2022  SPY     1      1      1      0    0    0    0
            GLD     0      0      0      0    0    0    0
```

I have tried the following `df = d=df.groupby(["date", "symbol","constituents"])["constituents"].count()` but it is not quite the shape I am looking for.

Comment: Why the row `GLD` is all zeros (`0`) ?

Comment: Note that you can use `sum` instead of `max` in the duplicate to have counts instead of dummies. `pivot_table` would also work.

Comment: please look at `df.pivot()` or `df.pivot_table()`

Comment: `df.pivot` won't work because of the duplicate values in date. Note that I want the date as index too.